# Add data based on quartiles

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

```
df 
     price vol       date
0      2    4     03-04-2020
1      4   24     03-04-2020 
2      5   10     03-04-2020
```

How could I add a calculate the average price if vol is above the 75th or below the 25 percentile for volumes that month?

I tried:

```
df.loc[df['avg_price_by_day_and_quartile']  = df[(df['avg_price_by_day_and_quartile'] > vol.quantile(.75) & <vol.quantile(.25) ).groupby(date')['quartile'].transform('mea‌​n')
```

Expected Output:

```
     price vol      date          quartile    avg_price_by_day_and_quartile
0     2    4      03-04-2020       below            2
1     4    24     03-04-2020       above            4
2     5    10     03-04-2020
```

Comment: take a look at `pd.qcut()` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html

Comment: row at index two has missing data ??